# How do I roll back the values of the items or collections after an unexpected error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, quasar-framework, es6-proxy

```
<q-select v-model="item" :options="colect">

<q-input v-model="item.name">

const colect = ref([... ])

const item = ref({... })
```

The dilemma is that, when trying to save the changes in the db if an unexpected error occurs I must go back the changes, but unfortunately the previous value of the item is not saved anywhere previously.

The question is: How do I prevent the item from also being modified in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

const temp = lodash.cloneDeep([...])

Cache the collection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).